# Trying to find the largest property of an object in a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to find the largest "SSN" in a Binary Search Tree comprised of "Persons", where each Person node stores an SSN in their info. However, iterating through the debugger, once I get the largest SSN which should be 11, the program jumps back into the if loop for some reason even though the local root Node is now null.

// "highestSSN" is passed in as 0
// rootNode is passed in as the root of my BST

```
public static int largestSSN(Node<Integer, Person> rootNode, int highestSSN) {
    if(rootNode != null) {
        if (rootNode.info.SSN > highestSSN)
            highestSSN = rootNode.info.SSN;
        largestSSN(rootNode.rightChild, highestSSN);
    }
    return highestSSN;
}
```

The program returns highestSSN as 11 and the rootNode is null, but then it jumps back into the line that reads "largestSSN(rootNode.rightChild, highestSSN);", and re-evaluates everything from the root node that's 11 to the original root, in backwards order. I'm not sure why this is?

Comment: Yeah but the rootNode becomes null when the node with the highest SSN (11) is evaluated, so the method should stop the recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the returned highestSSN. Try this:

```
public static int largestSSN(Node<Integer, Person> rootNode, int highestSSN) {
if(rootNode != null) {
//I think following 2 lines are useless, since BST already has rightNode.info.SSN greater than rootNode.SSN
    if (rootNode.info.SSN > highestSSN)
        highestSSN = rootNode.info.SSN;
    highestSSN=largestSSN(rootNode.rightChild, highestSSN);//***CHANGED
}
return highestSSN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how you implement your recursive call `largestSSN(rootNode.rightChild, highestSSN);`, you keep repeating it even after you get the value, the trick is you just return once you get the maximum value, otherwise you do your recursive call

Also, you don't need `highestSSN` in your method arguments

```
public static int largestSSN(Node<Integer, Person> rootNode) {
  if(rootNode.right == null) {
    return rootNode.info.SSN
  else{  
    return largestSSN(rootNode.rightChild);
  }
}
```